# function pointer for a member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

it would be kind of someone to help with the issue:

i have a function within a class

```
class A
{
   void fcn1(double *p, double *hx, int m, int n, void *adata);
   void fcn2();
}
```

inside fcn2 i am trying to use pointer to fcn1 as follows:

```
A::fcn2()
{
  void (*pfcn1)(double*, double*, int, int, void*) = fcn1;
}
```

and i am getting an error:

> error C3867: 'A::fcn': function call missing argument list; use '&A::fcn' to create a pointer to member

it would be kind of someone to help.

Thanks

Comment: Member functions are not functions. Think about it. You can't just *call* a member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fcn1()` is not a plain function but a member function.  You can't use an ordinary function pointer to store a pointer to it, because this doesn't provide enough information: what should `this` be set to when the function is called?

You need to use a *member* function pointer instead:

```
void (A::*pfcn1)(double*, double*, int, int, void*) = &A::fcn1;
```

If you have an object `a` of type `A`, you can later call it using:

```
(a.*pfcn1)(&somedouble, &somedouble, 42, 69, NULL);
```

If you have a pointer `pa` to an object of type `A`, you can later call it using:

```
(pa->*pfcn1)(&somedouble, &somedouble, 42, 69, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeSeymour -- didn't realise the parens were necessary!

Comment: Thanks Mike. may i aks a little more clarification. i eventually use this A::*pfcn1 to a function fcn3(void (*func)(double *p, double *hx, int m, int n, void *adata),/*has other arguments*/) which takes in a function pointer as the first argument. and follwing your example i was trying to pass it as this->*pfcn1 as the first argument. But that is breaking down.

Comment: @user1612986: It's really unclear what you're asking I'm afraid.  What do you mean by "i eventually use this A::*pfcn1 to a function fcn3"?

Comment: fcn3(void (*func)(double *p, double *hx, int m, int n, void *adata),/*has other arguments*/) has a signature like this. it is an optimizer which takes in a function pointer. I have A::fcn1() which i want to pass into the optimizer fcn3()'s as its first argument. All these steps i am doing within A::func2(). inside A::func2(){ first pfcn1 = &A::fcn1() as you suggested and then i want to pass it in fcn3(pfcn1,/*other arguments*/); }

Comment: @user1612986: Thanks, I see now. Unfortunately this is awkward to do: you essentially need to write a plain function `forward_to_fcn1(double *p, double *hx, int m, int n, void *adata) { get_the_right_A_object().fcn1(p, hx, m, n, adata); }`, and pass a pointer to *that* function to `fcn3()` as its 1st parameter instead.

Comment: The hard part is figuring out a way for `get_the_right_A_object()` to "know" which `A` object to operate on. Is there any data among the parameters that can be used to hold this identifying info?  (`adata` looks likely.)  If so, you can pass those parameters to `get_the_right_A_object()` as well and let it base its decision on that. Otherwise, as I've written it in the previous comment, its only option really is to use a global or `static` `A` object that you have previously set up (so you might as well just name the object instead of going via the `get_the_right_A_object()` function).

Comment: i think boost::bind gives a solution to this. But not sure how to use it.

Comment: @user1612986: boost::bind is a very nice alternative way to solve this problem, but TTBOMK it hands you a function object (which is like a supercharged function pointer -- it can be called like a function pointer, and can also keep around any extra state it needs) not a pointer to a function, and your `fcn3()` specifically requires a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
void (A::*pfcn1)(double*, double*, int, int, void*) = &A::fcn1;
```

Consider using a `typedef` for readability:

```
class A
{
   ...
   typedef void (A::*fcn1_ptr)(double*, double*, int, int, void*);
};

void A::fcn2()
{
    fcn1_ptr pfcn1 = &A::fcn1;
}
```