# passing non static member function pointer in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function pointer for a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514447/function-pointer-for-a-member-function)

I have to come up with some thing like below in C++.

I have a member function in following class.

```
class myClass {
public:
       void myFunc();

};
```

I have following function in another library which I should call and pass a call back function which is myFunc() of object

```
void AnotherFunction((void*)(pCallback)())
{
   // Here I will call back function
}
```

How can I acheive above? I am aware of static function of a class to pass a call back but here I have to make sure function is thread safe. With out using static how can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: What instance of `myClass` do you expect `pCallback` to be called on?

Comment: This has got to be a dupe of 9999 questions.

Comment: yes, basically, you will want it to be a member function pointer (see related questions) and think of the context.

Comment: Which won't help him at all if he needs a function pointer.

Comment: The requirements just don't make any sense. At all. *Class member functions are not functions*. You cannot *call* a class member function.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the "best" solution is to vomit an exception.

```
void f(void(*fp)()) { fp(); }
void mah_func() { 
    try { 
        throw; 
    } catch(my_class* m) {
        m->func();
    }
}
int main() {
    my_class m;
    try {
        throw &m;
    } catch(my_class* p) {
        f(mah_func);
    }
}
```

It's a disgusting abuse, but thread-safe and the most portable.

Comment: Awesome. Who says exceptions can't be useful?! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Internally, a member function always has the this-pointer as "invisible" first argument so your function would have the signature void(myClass *). If you can change the signature of AnotherFunction to `void AnotherFunction(std::function<void()> callback)` you could do the following:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void AnotherFunction(std::function<void()> callback)
{
  callback();
}

void fun()
{
  std::cout << "fun()" << std::endl;
}

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int i) : i_(i) { }

  static void gun()
  {
    std::cout << "Foo::gun()" << std::endl;
  }

  void hun()
  {
    std::cout << "Foo(" << i_ << ")::hun()" << std::endl;
  }

protected:
private:
  int i_;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo(666);
  AnotherFunction(fun);
  AnotherFunction(Foo::gun);
  AnotherFunction(std::bind(&Foo::hun, foo));
}
```

which prints:

```
fun()
Foo::gun()
Foo(666)::hun()
```

Comment: Says it's in another library. Kind of implies he can't.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Fiddling with static members is definitely not thread-safe which makes your solution pretty much the only possibility.