# Passing a method as pointer to function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function pointer for a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514447/function-pointer-for-a-member-function)

I have a problem, in a class, I have this method : `virtual void start(void *(*ptr)(void*), void *);`
In an other one, I want to call start with this method : `void *Room::run(void *p)`.

So I tried to do this : `thread->start(&Room::run, 0);` but the compiler doesn't want it because : `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void *(__thiscall Room::* )(void *)' to 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)'`

How can I resolve it ? Templates ? Or is there a more obvious solution ?
Thank you !

P.S : Just to precise, I need it to make threads (http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is Run a static method? If not you can not use it like that. An instance method is implicitly related to the instance(the `*this` pointer)

Comment: You could make a non-member function with the correct signature and pass that instead.

Comment: Well, sorry for the title.
And no, run is not a static method. So is it impossible to make it work without making it static ?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be static. the second `void*` parameter is where you can pass the object which the `start` will pass to the static function. In the static function you can cast the `void *` to the correct type, and then call whatever member functions you want.

Comment: If you have a member function and an object you wish to call it on, you could use std::bind to create a function object to pass.

Comment: @PeterWood : I didn't catch you. Is what you mean here the solution that Bart van Ingen posted ?

Comment: Yes, @Bart van Ingen Schenau's post shows what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, pointers to (freestanding) functions and pointers to methods are completely different beasts that can not be mixed.

If you want to pass a pointer-to-member-function to an API that needs a pointer-to-function, then the typical solution is to use a small wrapper function:

```
class Room {
public:
  void run();
  // other members omitted

  // wrapper function
  static void* run_wrapper(void* p)
  {
    static_cast<Room*>(p)->run();
    return NULL;
  }
};
```

And you use it like this:

```
thread->start(Room::run_wrapper, myRoomPointer);
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass the object myRoom but a pointer to the start method to meet the static_cast.

Comment: @harper: I assumed `myRoom` to be a pointer, but did not make that clear.

Comment: That needs to be `&Room::run_wrapper`. Memberfunctions don't implicitly convert to their address like free functions do.

Comment: @doomster: Static member functions follow the rules for free functions in this respect, so the `&` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against casting a function pointer to a `void *` pointer as, in c++ and possibly c as well, the sizes may be different.

Overall, your solution is not very c++. Admittedly, using a c library makes it a bit trickier. Here's the method I'm using on my current project:-

```
class ThreadBase
{
public:
  ThreadBase ()
  {
  }

  virtual ~ThreadBase ()
  {
    // TODO - inform thread to stop, using a message or a signal or something
    // and then wait for the thread to terminate
    void
      *return_value = 0;

    pthread_join (m_thread_handle, &return_value);
  }

  void Run ()
  {
    if (pthread_create (&m_thread_handle, 0, ThreadFunction, this))
    {
      // error - throw an exception or something
    }
  }

private:
  static void *ThreadFunction (void *param)
  {
    ThreadBase
      *thread = static_cast <ThreadBase *> (param);

    thread->Main ();

    return 0;
  }

  virtual void Main () = 0;

private:
  pthread_t
    m_thread_handle;
};
```

and then derive from ThreadBase the implementation specific versions:

```
class SomeThread : public ThreadBase
{
private:
  void Main ()
  {
    // do something
  }
};
```

You may want to alter `Main` to return an exit code and pass that back from the thread. And you need a way to make `Main` exit if it is in an infinite loop (e.g. if it's a listener consuming messages of some sort).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I'll study it but for now I'll keep the other one because I'm very short on timings.

Comment: @Florian: looking at the other one, they are effectively the same, this one is a bit more OO.

Comment: Sorry, but this inherently broken: Firstly, you can't start the thread in the constructor of the baseclass, because at that point the actual type is ThreadBase, leading to a call to a pure virtual function. Secondly, stopping the thread in the destructor is like deleting a file in fstream's destructor. Lastly, the implicit conversion to void* is paired with a reinterpret_cast. This should be a static_cast instead. If you don't want the simple solution above, consider using a C++ threading library like Boost's or the built-in C++11 one.

Comment: @doomster: you make some good points, this code was only based on my working code, my base class doesn't call a virtual Main, that virtual call is much later on, but you're right, there is a race condition between completing the constructor and the thread starting, not an issue in my version as the thread waited until a message arrived, well after the object was fully constructed. I'll amend the code.